# If clause in a recursive function

Tags: java, node.js, dom, if-statement

I am trying to build a function which traverse a Dom tree if and only if the node name is not equal to `script` and `style`. here is the function:

```
      public static void PostOrderTR(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException, MalformedURLException, SAXNotRecognizedException, SAXNotSupportedException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException
{

             if (node == null || node.getNodeName() == null)
                       {
                    return;
                       }
    if(!"script".equals(node.getNodeName())||!"style".equals(node.getLocalName())|| !"style".equals(node.getNodeName()))

             {
                 //do something
                  PostOrderTR(node.getFirstChild());
    }
               if(!"script".equals(node.getNodeName())||!"style".equals(node.getLocalName())|| !"style".equals(node.getNodeName()))

                    PostOrderTR(node.getNextSibling());

         }
```

but in practice, it results exactly opposite. it goes through all nodes including the `script` and `style`. I already tried to replace`&&` with `||` and nothing changed much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition doesn't work because all node names are either not "script" or not "style", so all node names pass.

The right condition is :

```
if(!("script".equals(node.getNodeName())||"style".equals(node.getLocalName()))
```

This means that the node name is neither "script" nor "style".

Comment: that is right! but why the way I wrote looks wrong? it still say the node name is not `style` or not `script`

Comment: @lonesome If the node name is "style", it is not "script", so your condition is true. If the node name is "script", it is not "style", so your condition is true. Any node name passes your condition.

Comment: oh, so when it is `style` it passes from first `||` and when it is `script` it passes from second `||`. am I right?